# Bootloader unlocking not working on Nokia T20

Tags: bootloader, tablet, nokia

I have been trying to install an Android 13 GSI my Nokia T20 WiFi tablet (Model TA-1392) reached its final update ever. However, in order to flash the GSI onto the tablet, it said that I needed to unlock the bootloader to do so. That hasn't been working either, as it gives me this error:

`FAILED (remote: 'Unlock bootloader fail. fb_verify_unlockkey')`

Help?

Many thanks, 
Saturanium

Update: The only command that I could use that did not register as an unknown command was `fastboot oem unlock`; which registered something other than `FAILED (remote: 'unknown cmd.')`

Comment: Based on quick research, looks like Nokia doesn't provide an official method to unlock the bootloader anymore, so you have to resort to [3rd-party solutions](https://community.phones.nokia.com/discussion/61353/why-do-i-have-to-buy-an-code-serial-key-to-bootloader-unlock-the-phone)

Comment: Are there any 3rd-party options available for Linux? The only computer that I have administrative power on is my laptop running on KDE Neon, an Ubuntu-based distro. I do have a windows 11 desktop that I can use but do not have admin powers to.